# Site restricting access to web scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a list of medical papers for authors and emails. But there is this one site on the list that I can't get the correct HTML for. When I view the HTML retrieved back from my email collector, I get something totally different from expected.

The Link is

```
https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/2292550320967404
```

the code for my email extractor is

```
import requests
import xlwt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint as pp

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('Emails')
ws.write(0,0,'Emails')

emailList= []
r=0

#add url of the page you want to scrape to urlString
urlString='https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/2292550320967404'

headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    }

#function that extracts all emails from a page you provided and stores them in a list
def emailExtractor(urlString):
    getH=requests.get(urlString, headers=headers)
    h=getH.text
    pp.pprint(getH.text)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(h,'html.parser')
    mailtos = soup.select('a[href^="mailto"]')
    for i in mailtos:
        print(i)
        href=i['href']
        try:
            str1, str2 = href.split(':')
        except ValueError:
            break
        
        emailList.append(str2)
        
        
            

emailExtractor(urlString)

#adding scraped emails to an excel sheet
for email in emailList:
    r=r+1
    print(email)
    ws.write(r,0,email)

wb.save('emails.xls')
```

HTML content I get back from request

```
('<!DOCTYPE html>\n'
 '<html lang="en-US">\n'
 '<head>\n'
 '    <title>Just a moment...</title>\n'
 '    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />\n'
 '    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />\n'
 '    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />\n'
 '    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />\n'
 '    <link href="/cdn-cgi/styles/challenges.css" rel="stylesheet" />\n'
 '    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="35">\n'
 '\n'
 '</head>\n'
 '<body class="no-js">\n'
 '    <div class="main-wrapper" role="main">\n'
 '    <div class="main-content">\n'
 '        <h1 class="zone-name-title h1">\n'
 '            <img class="heading-favicon" src="/favicon.ico"\n'
 '                 '
 'onerror="this.onerror=null;this.parentNode.removeChild(this)" />\n'
 '            journals.sagepub.com\n'
 '        </h1>\n'
 '        <h2 class="h2" id="challenge-running">\n'
 '            Checking if the site connection is secure\n'
 '        </h2>\n'
 '        <noscript>\n'
 '            <div id="challenge-error-title">\n'
 '                <div class="h2">\n'
 '                    <span class="icon-wrapper">\n'
 '                        <div class="heading-icon warning-icon"></div>\n'
 '                    </span>\n'
 '                    <span id="challenge-error-text">\n'
 '                        Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue\n'
 '                    </span>\n'
 '                </div>\n'
 '            </div>\n'
 '        </noscript>\n'
 '        <div id="trk_jschal_js" '
 'style="display:none;background-image:url(\'/cdn-cgi/images/trace/jsch/nojs/transparent.gif?ray=75849ed52fc9b0e8\')"></div>\n'
 '        <div id="challenge-body-text" class="core-msg spacer">\n'
 '            journals.sagepub.com needs to review the security of your '
 'connection before proceeding.\n'
 '        </div>\n'
 '        <form id="challenge-form" '
 'action="/doi/10.1177/2292550320967404?__cf_chl_f_tk=bHqq3i2bKdEfEiT1peZEcdWQa9k9tTz37aYRYHI_QcM-1665460109-0-gaNycGzNB70" '
 'method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">\n'
 '            <input type="hidden" name="md" '
 'value="FP_IxizCpqEmvGI4Cz2yWSRbBHmc4OxUNN_7RF1EZog-1665460109-0-AWhwIS9WH9D4GsJKlTfFUsr8lSenJ_R6-D3xH7aJejLGRLOxgwGfV323iqa4uMQ3C0QYbo2G-I-EjaTwbKqNd-hc02NoSUqmU4TpmCmCfV9N62KeOjIc1ttXQInrR81OCWY1J9GwLUT-BGEoLp2h0JR4OSDkiyYYH7bZucGMGsGh_xZGur7xyOj1__fa0T_BCO0oInQAoBTPrijaEfYAGepll_lbcxaS2y_HwH8ZJt9bGfNLZBKM68V1ajFFVCPcXUBjvfS48Nj955ad4j2QDRTRbYbOODsuOR1uUS0Q_cnpBJey15W6awA4fDFKkCDGZoUR8TvfzwtWmUsgGjcIVbBYviemw2lL7iJ5b_Xt_nFb-IarAJPDIjF6AkCDM-5CE-2sIH6oYN-pZavHi1z2bkY4u4juUUg9syZUUkPOTEgrIzqG3UFrCR2GaG9serSATexdQcTQrX_LWOqeXR03zNCbOlZWNSo0FmEnKjZDANFXVXjpPewWFghbzVIunaDjaQ_Qbqr_KCHTdfQv-Tt6TIeJKqE0IU9MIT3d12r3S1Uzd7T5tzdG9JfEpp3OJiOjJKZxPUjfRtwlaTxsjjJUboocsU8O7h9l1GDz3nFjGiIFHyXoq78TjekMOo0m6k4kptpSnWY-xbR_4vLp2qZ0Y74ww_SXi46vEMlipd11ehv9dm7qqLxRlpPoarwuRTLkbg" '
 '/>\n'
 '            <input type="hidden" name="r" '
 'value="NPXbn0lYUetIsYcs1MPGUCg2t_e5NEH8pJVfPmSIKic-1665460109-0-AQ9iw34MWM/JZiLSyNEP2AHmaCb2MTvN8eNvkJ1l93rsw0l6dXRenSMB9TnCPgc1B1aISxwM379yvCHCOZGPyRKsBEnl2bEoHhKmL97ErgHOuR6KGZaLYv/0zGtw4pPo+TnSOiEzMGhqEJWsmSELNNiYX450JjlXeGfqDAf1jo8pY7AWjTHY5xL5CEHpxAGdnTdE0Cv9bzohvRiI0u1Vg1BdkVLhTMWZkZ6CCJJkk/Rto4QnrWdUhL442L1TFSBoiH5OZ9+7fV3TiFa4mWackHJuVVOFF6HbElFFq0Z+7/uovFI5wZiUKr/ygPfGPsrl5Yqa7zfvWDU9YLV6MCyWInGgl6pwhtwl8JWsVLbYRx1R2JQQhr7ZNzf7+xDnRdWcTKN5Dw1/DNM2HuavPRJyctiNEckzoB15AmA18a9rlwCU8PH/EgDm8hnjI9+HzjSdUm3z4hUxFh1qUZSjYwe4h3q+1iIT8ELL2PjiSf9v2itSD5GbP460Vzfbb1w3iMotcc2rAVg7Z6INlqsVCLly3+tsfXU8SuRGAjD/MCaWf7QcEDd9844t2Yi6ZsJiAASBjdpvTJrAOedYi64JDEpG+EF+enxVXD9tUGlWVl2w9sldmFmmlNInYd2QVpy/BDxamCI4FEDuiWZj2IMeJZKiNzeJIKbu0Lyjb7hibVDnXM0lXJleBEM4Pypm+zv76RKYC8vUl4DsLcWDPhjKjiHibV2CwQaAz/Tk4A50n4J7dvnOX8f1kTSP26JFpI9/UJceRN7ne8ATcV2UpdI+Ut2nPRf5YGOFkF6LAEbnGKLidMVAfapTWSBdUAfPxAd+Q5i82lzXpobjpi33AzVZNbOUgX72ODDM6tZj+XJCe9tlgQG+0H84PKAfjDnItnPJKGNYrZXm8lNoqj62a8VyBrupwwFb0cDrfqsUVWZkrq9b8Z6PKIFYa5zxfZXD2Uqh8awlPKsA/tUHVloYbBDiW72YYe2MRkqkA4LS140eTTutqxhdyZ6HFWcT9vzt5zqUaYPXZFWKiFiPmtVKtcWGT1OCVsRkPnhElZ2naBUNhCEoAWeg79uSF9IQ7gY+f7tF0jZ/fHYt4bGrlOHZX3alu1iytmgGH/hwN09eDQ2t5MHsBz8pIdQ6nHitMcyNZqIg58EC1f+H0VhmRI9cIxh3UlDfPHjdbE+1QSBnSYC4NHUc7dQ9IZRqZzdJbfTdmlhNhRRWMSQoCfKNML0keY/dDZ8izdLB2YKrOF6gB+BDdhJv+2OwSzEGMDDh9bJcbLYDKGfW9XZrMPGvBADe7AUE9uyTjx1XwpxZYypgcLRtnUmgaZrCYjKF5prMn2WiTIlvtpK9ZpafjNeF3h9ovxsZWmDVD6PtPxlbLIDLmdw4Mg0RYiKCMI/H6kUdubhlbd1trF9+Di+kt/ZtiPq5EfFYop7g6Zn+FNcm6VPncctX9L1bksocMMEPgipj8+WlUQCRHAQXrgO/DvYKKoRJoBCRzDJp/MIeWpAejyuDPzztxmNyQldWWVAKAcewFCvTUYM919RDQv84NSFLgYPV0SYq/A/9aAFWxwrcCZKEc4z//8LXq+29AWq5ws8SoAxD6Tkc3o9suYFPJwfNPJQpas+0jAM2W5xIVF6yNKGjGcAPZf4gfR26B2AwAp/y0mpNPHx8gZhOXBHsrPmesAfRuTrcYOQffmVm5CXx9SDDiDuJxoYirI/2kUwW27njs09CBFebvp7UsufH25sYmQ0u702s3H3fvhkRuTuopVtwMUnkPm0qU4JgxAWXJycL6+T8qpLuoGQRshjzsN/OLIdh1L0MbvieHsuRKtVbt+6HshdPb1NhebeLQkWJwERoWEOYrabMr6Mj3rA3W8HJqtewR6gS1cyOHmCCwlmN6qzFfxvQdErtGD0W1WeIOw2RE1hMGwxZKejDDw=="/>\n'      
 '        </form>\n'
 '    </div>\n'
 '</div>\n'
 '<script>\n'
 '    (function(){\n'
 '        window._cf_chl_opt={\n'
 "            cvId: '2',\n"
 "            cType: 'non-interactive',\n"
 "            cNounce: '1443',\n"
 "            cRay: '75849ed52fc9b0e8',\n"
 "            cHash: '96300899c16d111',\n"
 '            cUPMDTk: '
 '"\\/doi\\/10.1177\\/2292550320967404?__cf_chl_tk=bHqq3i2bKdEfEiT1peZEcdWQa9k9tTz37aYRYHI_QcM-1665460109-0-gaNycGzNB70",\n'
 "            cFPWv: 'g',\n"
 "            cTTimeMs: '1000',\n"
 '            cTplV: 4,\n'
 "            cTplB: 'cf',\n"
 '            cRq: {\n'
 '                ru: '
 "'aHR0cHM6Ly9qb3VybmFscy5zYWdlcHViLmNvbS9kb2kvMTAuMTE3Ny8yMjkyNTUwMzIwOTY3NDA0',\n"
 '                ra: '
 "'TW96aWxsYS81LjAgKFdpbmRvd3MgTlQgMTAuMDsgV2luNjQ7IHg2NCkgQXBwbGVXZWJLaXQvNTM3LjM2IChLSFRNTCwgbGlrZSBHZWNrbykgQ2hyb21lLzk5LjAuNDg0NC44MiBTYWZhcmkvNTM3LjM2',\n"
 "                rm: 'R0VU',\n"
 '                d: '
 "'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',\n"
 "                t: 'MTY2NTQ2MDEwOS42MzgwMDA=',\n"
 "                m: 'Rf64Ehi/NXMq+Vq/iBkBLCqFiwJ2RAPApYPZyBEHyjA=',\n"
 "                i1: '3tUuIPzCitZIwZCVZK+phQ==',\n"
 "                i2: 'TtKyFlZn29GJOLSSWtLHgw==',\n"
 "                zh: 'gw7YMdbZ1M4iQ6cbqLPC730Ml6kaQ+3i4OTRjaElasU=',\n"
 "                uh: 'FG/rQB5A3oMsViSOvzHy/Yz4Yg41uhiEOKdRek6QBDY=',\n"
 "                hh: 'c9ogzZPyf3xtUVOiYSAQbEsbym/d5b1rPQM2Rm/OUTE=',\n"
 '            }\n'
 '        };\n'
 "        var trkjs = document.createElement('img');\n"
 "        trkjs.setAttribute('src', "
 "'/cdn-cgi/images/trace/jsch/js/transparent.gif?ray=75849ed52fc9b0e8');\n"
 "        trkjs.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');\n"
 '        document.body.appendChild(trkjs);\n'
 "        var cpo = document.createElement('script');\n"
 '        cpo.src = '
 "'/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/orchestrate/jsch/v1?ray=75849ed52fc9b0e8';\n"
 "        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash = location.hash === '' && "
 "location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1 ? '#' : location.hash;\n"
 "        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery = location.search === '' && "
 "location.href.slice(0, -window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash.length).indexOf('?') !== "
 "-1 ? '?' : location.search;\n"
 '        if (window.history && window.history.replaceState) {\n'
 '            var ogU = location.pathname + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery + '
 'window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash;\n'
 '            history.replaceState(null, null, '
 '"\\/doi\\/10.1177\\/2292550320967404?__cf_chl_rt_tk=bHqq3i2bKdEfEiT1peZEcdWQa9k9tTz37aYRYHI_QcM-1665460109-0-gaNycGzNB70" '
 '+ window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash);\n'
 '            cpo.onload = function() {\n'
 '                history.replaceState(null, null, ogU);\n'
 '            };\n'
 '        }\n'
 "        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);\n"
 '    }());\n'
 '</script>\n'
 '\n'
 '    <div class="footer" role="contentinfo">\n'
 '        <div class="footer-inner">\n'
 '            <div class="clearfix diagnostic-wrapper">\n'
 '                <div class="ray-id">Ray ID: '
 '<code>75849ed52fc9b0e8</code></div>\n'
 '            </div>\n'
 '            <div class="text-center">Performance &amp; security by <a '
 'rel="noopener noreferrer" '
 'href="https://www.cloudflare.com?utm_source=challenge&utm_campaign=j" '
 'target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></div>\n'
 '        </div>\n'
 '    </div>\n'
 '</body>\n'
 '</html>\n')
```

Comment: A custom scraper that I wrote gets this page with no problem. Considering you did not include what your headers are I can't tell you if they are insufficient, but I bet they are. Make sure you use a real `User-Agent` and `ssl certificate`.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy sorry i edited and added my user agent

Comment: How do I add a ssl certificate?? @OneMadGypsy

Comment: I'm not positive this matters, but it's 'User-Agent', not 'user-agent'. You can add an ssl certificate like this `import certifi
requests.get(urlString, headers=headers, verify=certifi.where()).text`

Comment: I refactored your script with proper headers and ssl. It still didn't work. On first glance it would seem javascript is mandatory to view the site, but my browser has no problem opening the page without it. I have no clue why the page won't behave. Which just makes me want to figure this out even more.

Comment: What browser are you using @OneMadGypsy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248721/discussion-between-onemadgypsy-and-carter-james).

Comment: And exactly I don't understand either

Comment: You won't be able to get the email addresses - they are protected and generated/decoded by javascript in page. The less complex (and therefore optimal) way forward is to use selenium in this case. If you can do without emails, then there are other non-selenium solutions.

Comment: How could you tell the emails were generated by JS @BarrythePlatipus

Answer (score 3):

Avoiding detection is one of the primary issues of any web scraper. Modern websites have developed lots of techniques to properly fingerprint a browser, and it's not limited to your IP or `User-Agent`. For example, even the way your browser renders the font can give up a bot from a real person accessing the website.

As an engineer working on web scraping, I would suggest you at least use a pool of proxies (ideally residential) for your scraper and also implement some of the techniques highlighted [here](https://www.php8legs.com/en/php-web-scraper/51-how-to-avoid-selenium-webdriver-from-being-detected-as-bot-or-web-spider).

Additionally, you could use a third party web scraping service. The API we've built has a high success rate and it even offers a built in way to extract elements. For example, using the `extract_rules` parameter on the website you've mention, like this:

```py
import requests

API_KEY = '<YOUR_API_KEY>'
SCRAPER_URL = 'https://api.webscrapingapi.com/v1'

TARGET_URL = 'https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/2292550320967404'

PARAMS = {
    "api_key":API_KEY,
    "url": TARGET_URL,
    "render_js":1,
    "extract_rules":'{"emails":{"selector":"a[href^=\'mailto:\']","output":"text"}}',
}

response = requests.get(SCRAPER_URL, params=PARAMS)

print(response.text)
```

Returns a JSON object including all emails:

```js
{
   "emails":[
      "zhxf9304@126.com",
      "zhxf9304@126.com",
      "zhxf9304@126.com",
      "zhxf9304@126.com",
      "zhxf9304@126.com",
      "190905761@qq.com"
   ]
}
```

Of course, you can also use it to extract the raw HTML, by not sending the `extract_rules` parameter.

Coming back to your script. Inspecting the HTML in your question gives away a couple of hints:

> ```
> <h2 class="h2" id="challenge-running">
>        Checking if the site connection is secure
> </h2>
> ```

> ```
> <span id="challenge-error-text">\n'
>      Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue\n'
> </span>\n'
> ```

This tells us that:

1. The website might greet you with a captcha challenge
2. You need to render JavaScript files on that particular website

This means that using just request is not enough. You need a way to access the website from a real web browser. Since your implementation is in Python, take a look at Selenium for this job.

Here is an implementation example of your script, but with Selenium instead of requests:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

emailList= []

urlString='https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/2292550320967404'

def emailExtractor(urlString):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(urlString)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    mailtos = soup.select('a[href^="mailto"]')
    for i in mailtos:
        print(i)
        href=i['href']
        try:
            str1, str2 = href.split(':')
        except ValueError:
            break
        
        emailList.append(str2)
            
emailExtractor(urlString)

for email in emailList:
    print(email)
```

P.S. I've stripped a few things from your code for simplicity, but you got the basic idea and you can add them back.